# How to mirror this BeizerPath for rtl languages ios

Tags: ios, swift, arabic-support

Iam using UIBeizerPath for drawing stepsdotview, Please help in fliping the BeizerPath, check the code in attached image

Check the code:

```
    public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let availableSpace = bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
    let availableSpaceForLines = availableSpace - (dotRadius * 2) * CGFloat(numberOfSteps)
    var lineWidth: CGFloat = availableSpaceForLines
    if numberOfLines > 0 {
        lineWidth = availableSpaceForLines / CGFloat(numberOfLines)
    }
    let origin = CGPoint(x: insets.left, y: (bounds.height - (dotDiameter)) / 2.0)
    let dotSize = CGSize(width: dotDiameter, height: dotDiameter)
    var dotRect = CGRect(origin: origin, size: dotSize)

    //Create dots and lines
    for index in 0 ..< numberOfSteps {
        var dotColor = unSelectedColor
        if index <= selectedIndex {
            dotColor = dotColors[index] ?? selectedIndexColor
        }
        dotColor.setFill()
        //Draw line
        if index > 0 {
            let xCoordinate = dotRect.origin.x - lineWidth + dotRadius / 2
            let yCoordinate = dotRect.midY - lineHeight / 2.0
            let lineOrigin = CGPoint(x: xCoordinate, y: yCoordinate)
            let lineSize = CGSize(width: lineWidth - dotRadius, height: lineHeight)
            let lineRect = CGRect(origin: lineOrigin, size: lineSize)
            let leftLine = UIBezierPath(rect: lineRect)
            dotColor.setFill()
            leftLine.fill()
        }
        //Draw dot
        let dot = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: dotRect)
        dot.fill()
        //Frame for next dot
        dotRect.origin.x += dotDiameter + lineWidth
    }
}
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3wJW.png**strong text**

Comment: Copy/paste code, not screenshots

Comment: please check it now

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet, using rotation angle works

```
    path.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -bounds.midX, y: -bounds.midY))
    path.apply(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi))
    path.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY))
```